# how to separate name and add according to it?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Table called `Product` and columns are `ID`, `Pname`, `Profit`, `Loss`, `Month`. Total
first six month `Total=Sum(Profit)-Sum(Loss)`, in one column called `Col1` and last six month `Total=Sum(Profit)-Sum(Loss)` in one column called `Col2` separated by their `Pname`.

Sample Input:

```
ID  PName  Month  Profit  Loss
--  -----  -----  ------  ----
1   A      JAN    5       2
2   B      FEB    4       2
3   A      MAR    10      3
4   B      Nov    5       2
```

Expected Output

```
PName  Col1  col2
-----  ----  ----
A      10    0
B      2     3
```

What will be the way to do this in SQL Server?

Answer (score 2):

This seems to do the job:

```
declare @t table (ID int not null,PName char(1) not null,Month char(3) not null,
                  Profit int not null,Loss int not null)
insert into @t(ID,PName,Month,Profit,Loss) values
(1,'A','JAN',5,2),
(2,'B','FEB',4,2),
(3,'A','MAR',10,3),
(4,'B','Nov',5,2)

;With Halves as (
    select PName,
        CASE WHEN Month in ('Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun') THEN 1
            ELSE 2 END as Half,
        Profit - Loss as Net
    from @t
)
select PName,
    COALESCE([1],0) as Col1,
    COALESCE([2],0) as Col2
from Halves pivot (SUM(Net) for Half in ([1],[2])) p
```

I'd usually recommend against having a column called `Month` (since it's a keyword) and would more normally expect it to be e.g. a `date` column fixed on the 1st of the appropriate month (and either have a relevant year or be for a fixed year also)

I've taken one simplifying step that `SUM(Profit) - SUM(Loss)` is the same as `SUM(Profit - Loss)`

Comment: is it possible without using pivot and COALESCE?

Comment: @user3158245 - maybe, but that's like asking for help with using screws to join two pieces of wood, and then after someone's suggested an appropriate tool, you then asking if it can be done without using a screwdriver.

Comment: SUM(Profit) - SUM(Loss) is the same as SUM(Profit - Loss) but if i want to divide it like SUM(PROFIT)/SUm(loss) what should i do?